# Passing a method to be used with a defer as an argument

Tags: go, error-handling

We can easily pass a function as a parameter and use it with `defer`:

```
func main() {
    test(rec)
}

func test(f func(int)) {
    defer f(10)
    panic("test")
}

func rec(v int) {
    e := recover()
    fmt.Println(e)
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

This works. [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AmgCteQsMxI).

---

But what if we need to pass a **method** and then call `recover` in that method?

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Data string
}

func main() {
    a := &MyStruct{}
    test(a.Recover)
}

func test(f func(int)) {
    defer f(10)
    panic("test")
}

func (m *MyStruct) Recover(arg int) {
    e := recover()
    fmt.Println(e)
    fmt.Println(arg)
}
```

Here we get some strange behavior, which I do not fully understand. [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NkylTc7sem_D).

It seems like the method get called but `recover` returns `nil` and after that there is a (another?) panic. None of the golang docs and google results has helped me to understand the reason of such behavior. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `recover()` function [returns nil when not called directly from the deferred function](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Handling_panics).

A call through the [method value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values) `a.Recover` is not a direct call.

Use a wrapper function that calls recover and the method:

```
func main() {
    a := &MyStruct{}
    test(func(arg int) { a.Recover(arg, recover()) })
}

func test(f func(int)) {
    defer f(10)
    panic("test")
}

func (m *MyStruct) Recover(arg int, e interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(e)
    fmt.Println(arg)
}
```

Another option is to use a [method expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions), but this is probably straying from what you are trying to accomplish:

```
func main() {
    a := &MyStruct{}
    test(a, (*MyStruct).Recover)
}

func test(a *MyStruct, f func(*MyStruct, int)) {
    defer f(a, 10)
    panic("test")
}

func (m *MyStruct) Recover(arg int) {
    e := recover()
    fmt.Println(e)
    fmt.Println(arg)
}
```

Comment: It wasn't clear from the docs that a call through a method value is not a direct call, but now I see... 
Thank you for clarification!
Do I understand correctly that there is no way to distinguish method value from method expression in a passed in argument?

Comment: Do you (or does anyone) know why a call through a method value is not considered a direct call?

Comment: The number of arguments for a method value is one less than the number of arguments for the underlying method. It follows from this that the call to the method value is not a direct call to the method.  Given a function at runtime, it's not possible to determine if the function is a plain function, function literal, method expression or method value.